# 1. Sum up specific rows in pandas data frame 2. create new data frame containing overall value

Tags: python, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame similar to this one.

```
Name    Asset
A       2
B       5
C       2
B       3
A       4
A       5
C       1
```

Now I want to sum up all assets == A, B and C. At the end I want to create a new data frame and store the overall sum in one row together with the name. Like this:

```
Name    Asset
A       11
B       8
C       3
```

Do you now a nice and easy way how to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), applying a sum. Try this code:

```
df.groupby(['Name']).sum()
```

and gives:

```
      Asset
Name       
A        11
B         8
C         3
```